# Erro: Não é possível converter Implicitamente

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro.

> Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "System.Linq.IQueryable" em "TesteMercos.Models.ApplicationProduct". Existe uma conversão explícita ?

nessa parte do código:

```
public ApplicationProduct GetProductsIdAsync(long products)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = _context.Produtos.Where(x => x.Id == products);

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Só me faz um favor, tira esse `try-ctach`, ele só está prejudicando seu código e fazendo nada útil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creio que sua variável `long products` seja o identificador do produto que você quer encontrar. Quando você realiza o filtro pelo método `Where()`, você irá obter uma coleção de dados, seja ela um `IQueryable` ou `IEnumerable`.

Para buscar o registro pelo identificador tente utilizar o método `FirstOrDefault()`, onde você passa sua condição e irá te retornar o primeiro registro que atender sua condição, caso ele exista. Se não encontrar irá te retornar nulo:

```
public ApplicationProduct GetProductsIdAsync(long id)
{
    return _context.Produtos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

Comment: Você podia ter tirado esse `try-ctach`, ele só está prejudicando seu código e fazendo nada útil. O pessoal faz isso porque lê em algum lugar assim e acha que é certo. Em uma resposta o pessoal vai fazer igual e vai justificar que é porque você ensinou assim, mesmo que seja só porque a pergunta fez errado. O motivo das pessoas fazerem errado não é que elas não sabem, é que tem gente demais ensinando errado. Nós precisamos ter responsabilidade na hora que passamos uma informação na internet porque ela será consumida por muita gente.

Comment: Realmente faz sentido. Vou me atentar mais a esses pontos. Crítica construtiva, obrigado.